# Is indexing on an IQueryable possible without converting to List?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a Razor Pages web application where my onget method has a LINQ query that finds a collection of no more than 5 records (my source is very large SQL view I've created):

```cs
IQueryable<int> ShipmentQtys = _MyContext
    .MaxShipmentEntries
    .Where(m => m.PartNo == currentPart)
    .Select(m => m.ShipQty);
```

It's speedy, but the problem is that I need to index off of the results. I know that I need to use .ToList() instead, but this significantly slows down my load time by a long shot, I'm assuming because my view is huge, so I'm stuck on how to get around the problem.

I need to index it in order to display each record (up to 5) in 5 fields that I have defined in my application. One post suggested using .ElementAt, but that is not supported in LINQ.

```cs
ShipQtyField1 = ShipmentQtys[0];
ShipQtyField2 = ShipmentQtys[1];
//etc.
```

Is there another way I can index an IQueryable(or an IEnumerable), or an alternative to indexing at all in my circumstance?

Comment: `.Take(5).ToList()` ? This will always be a bit slow because it's only when you start enumerating values that you actually execute (or compile + execute) the query. But yes there are other ways to consume a queryable or enumerable.

Comment: Or if you're saying that your query can only ever return five results, and it's still slow the second time you run it (i.e. after EF has cached a query plan) then I'd check that your query actually runs fast in SQL, e.g. have you indexed the partNo column? What does the execution plan look like in SSMS - are there table scans?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you access the records through the index instead of first `ToList()`ing it and then using the index? Do you expect it to be faster this way?

Comment: OK: that's because you're not actually running the database query until you put ToList in.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the index, by using the select overload

```
  var tmp = new <yourtype>[i];
  ShipmentQtys.Select((x,i) => tmp[i] = x);
```

That's the same as ToArray, it's just for demonstration;

Or you can enumerate the IEnumerable

```
  var e = ShipmentQtys.GetEnumerator();
  if (e.MoveNext())
     ShipQtyField1 = e.Current;
  if (e.MoveNext())
     ShipQtyField2 = e.Current;
```

For your dedicated variables, I would recommend the latter version.

But there is no way for a random access, it's always continuous access only.